# wsgi django and random 500

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have an application working on apache2. I wish to switch to uwsgi. 
After deployment I have faced fancy problem with random errors like :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
30928-    response = self.get_response(request)
30929-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
30930-    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
30931-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
30932-    return callback(request, **param_dict)
30933-  File "/var/www/fancy_site/releases/current/fancy_site/utils/views.py", line 699, in server_error
30934-    'GIGYA_API_KEY':settings.GIGYA_API_KEY,
30935-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 123, in render
30936-    return self._render(context)
30937-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 60, in instrumented_test_render
30938-    return self.nodelist.render(context)
30939-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
30940-    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
30941-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
30942-    return node.render(context)
30943-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 105, in render
30944-    compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)
30945-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 102, in get_parent
30946-    return get_template(parent)
30947-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 157, in get_template
30948-    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
30949-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 134, in find_template
30950-    source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
30951-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 42, in __call__
30952-    return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
30953-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 48, in load_template
30954-    template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
30955-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 168, in get_template_from_string
30956-    return Template(source, origin, name)
30957-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/template.py", line 37, in new_template_init
30958-    old_template_init(self, template_string, origin, name)
30959-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 108, in __init__
30960-    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
30961-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 136, in compile_string
30962-    return parser.parse()
30963-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 239, in parse
30964-    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
30965-  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 1054, in load
30966-    (taglib, e))
30967-django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'sso_token' is not a valid tag library: Template library sso_token not found, tried django.templatetags.sso_token,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.sso_token,django.contrib.webdesign.templatetags.sso_token,paging.templatetags.sso_token,sentry.templatetags.sso_token,tinymce.templatetags.sso_token,pagination.templatetags.sso_token,rosetta.templatetags.sso_token,flatblocks.templatetags.sso_token,oembed.templatetags.sso_token,debug_toolbar.templatetags.sso_token,memcache_status.templatetags.sso_token,mailchimp.templatetags.sso_token
```

django send me similar exceptions on mail like :  no module name views - which is ofcourse not true, because this application works on apache since two years : )

I have no idea where the problem is - I know I am not able to reproduce it at my stage env - which is a clone production machine. As far as I know it's not a code depend error or application problem.

at procution I am using current configuration:

I am using :
django 1.3.1
uWSGI 1.1
nginx 1.0.12-1~dotdeb.0
python 2.6
debian 6.0.3
2 x QC Xeon E5540 with 8 gb ram

those machines are under physicall load balancer supported by hosting company.

nginx cfg  :

```
server { 
  listen 80;
        server_name www.fancy_site.fancy_domain fancy_site.fancy_domain
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        access_log /path/to/file.log;

        if ($host = 'fancy_site' ) {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.fancy_site.fancy_domain/$1 permanent;
        }

        location /media/ {
            alias /path/to/media/;
            expires max;
        }

        location  /site_media/ {
            alias /path/to/media/;
            expires max;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias   /path/to/static/;
            expires max;
        }

        gzip  on;
        gzip_http_version 1.0;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 3;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;

        location / {
            uwsgi_pass unix://path/to/uwsgi.socket;
            include uwsgi_params;
        }

}
```

uWSGI cfg :

```
prefix = /path/to/prod_direcotry
master = true
processes = 80
uid = fancy_application
gid = www-data
memory-report = true
max-requests = 800
stdout_logfile = /path/to/uwsgi.log
daemonize = /path/to/uwsgi.log
redirect_stderr = true
logfile-chown=www-data
socket = /path/to/uwsgi.socket
chdir = /path/to/application_direcotry
pythonpath = /path/to/to_current_release_of_application
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=application_direcotry.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
touch-reload = %(prefix)/touch_to_restart
```

I'd like to ask You community if someone had the same or similar problem. Maybe someone solved and wish to share with how ?

regards
Lukasz

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are seeing other errors you should try to understand the error your getting as most likely that's really what the cause is.

In your case you're missing a templatetags library (named sso_token).  Most likely that means you failed to install a dependency on your production machine, or your INSTALLED_APPS are different between production and dev and your missing the app that provides that library.

This is very very unlikely to be caused by your deployment and much much more likely to be caused by discontinuity between your production and dev environments.

Comment: hey, thx for answer.  I do not think so because I am using the same package on apache and uwsgi  - and application works on apache without any problem.
About difrences in envs - I do not think so, because my stage is the same as prod - it's a mirror.

Comment: @user1286500 Can you manually import the sso_token inside manager shell on production server? Also, find and remove all pyc files first.

Comment: Yes I can, all pyc are removed after restarting uwsgi

Comment: I have tested the apache version - it works stable - there is no problem at all with it.